# FeedMe Inner field mapping

Tags: plugin-feedme

According to the CraftCMS [FeedMe 4 docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/content-mapping/field-types.html#inner-element-fields) we should be able to import inner element field data when importing content via FeedMe.

I have a section we'll call `Parent`, which has two fields that need importing; `ImportId` (text field) and `ChildEntry` (Entry relationship). Child Entry has two fields, Title and Body.

I am able to map `Parent->ImportId` and `ChildEntry->Title` I am unable to map to `ChildEntry->Body`.

*My JSON looks like this:*

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "secrets",
      "import_id": "UUID-9-3/4",
      "child_title": "Harry Potter",
      "child_message": "Is in a dream",
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Is this expected functionality, or am I reading the documentation correctly?

Comment: What type of field is ChildEntry->Body? Could it be that this is not a text field (but a Matrix field for instance), and therefore FeedMe can not use it for import?

Comment: It's a rich text field.

Comment: This should work, I just did that recently. Would you share a bit more Information? Maybe a Screenshot of the current Setup?

Answer (score 2):

You should nest the *child*'s details like so:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "secrets",
            "import_id": "UUID-9-3/4",
            "child": {
                "child_title": "Harry Potter",
                "child_message": "Is in a dream"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then make sure you you choose `data` as your **Primary Element** when mapping your feed and check **Create entries if they do not exist** for the relational field.